# How to pass an array of objects as uniforms to custom shader in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I would like to pass an array of Javascript objects to my custom shader written with `THREE.RawShaderMaterial` but still haven't been able to figure out how to achieve this.

Specifically, I would like to manually perform the same thing as `THREE.PointLightSource`. I am currently achieving this by using Three.js's functionality:

```
var matrixUniforms = {

    projectionMat: { value: new THREE.Matrix4() },

    modelViewMat: { value: new THREE.Matrix4() },

    normalMat: { value: new THREE.Matrix3() },

};

var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [

        matrixUniforms,

        THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ],

    ] ),

    vertexShader: $( "#" + vShader ).text(),

    fragmentShader: $( "#" + fShader ).text(),

    lights: true,

} );
```

Let's say I have

```
var pointLights = [ 
                   { position: new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0),

                     color: new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1) },

                   { position: new THREE.Vector3(10,10,10),

                     color: new THREE.Vector3(2,2,2) }
                  ];
```

How can I add it to uniforms of `THREE.RawShaderMaterial`? Is there any easy way to pass an array of objects that has the same properties? I may have found its solution for the older version of Three.js but couldn't find a way to do it with the latest version (r84).

EDIT:
I found [this thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10759) and [this thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2720). However, it seems that it is not documented anywhere...